# How to remove bottom black bar or spacing in gnome terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have this strange space/black bar between the bottom bar/dock and my terminal. I believe it's part of the gnome terminal as it scales (less noticeable when the terminal is small).

What is it and how do I remove it?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Probably part of the terminal window.

Comment: "What is it" It's padding because the maximized terminal area's size is not an integer multiple of an individual character cell's size. "How do i remove it" what would you want to have there instead? Unmaximize your terminal and then it'll be gone.

Comment: Any solution here .. I am also want to remove it. how can I do thit. it only appear when I maximize my terminal.

Comment: @egmont If I don't want to see it when I maximize my screen so how can I do that ?

Comment: @HNazmulHassan I assume you understand the basic mathematics, for example, if you're given a room of 320x410 cm and you want to cover the floor with tiles of 50x50 cm, you _are_ going to have partial tiles at some of the edges. Is this clear so far? With this in mind, could you please describe how you _exactly_ wish your screen to look like?